# R code: Modifying Built in Function on lapply list

Tags: r, regression

I have a list of regression models, but I would like to run stepwise with forward method.
I tried to modify this function with lapply, but it doesn't really work..

I have a data

```
test<-data.frame(X1=rnorm(50,mean=50,sd=10),
             X2=rnorm(50,mean=5,sd=1.5),
             X3=rnorm(50,mean=200,sd=25))
test$X1[10]<-5
test$X2[10]<-5
test$X3[10]<-530
```

I run regression models

```
varlist <- names(test)

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
lm(substitute(i~., list(i = as.name(x))), data = data 
})
```

And then run stepwise..

```
lapply(models, function(x){step(x,direction="forward")})
```

However, it doesn't affect my modification of stepwise methods- forward..
How I could modify built in function on lapply?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: (1) Your example code has some typos in it, (2) What exactly doesn't work? Once I fix the part of your code that actually fits the models, everything works as it appears it should. Can you expand on exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Please show us what you expect to get and what you are getting, and why you think it's "wrong."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stepwise using 'forward' or 'both', you need to include a scope argument. For you, the scope would be something like the full potential equation. For example on X1: `scope='X1~X2+X3'`. However, after step 1 of models, you have a list of 3 equations, where each equation uses all the possible variables. Therefore, stepwise cannot possibly add any new variables.

Instead, try "backward". This does not require a scope argument, and it shows that the syntax is correct. I've corrected your code below:

```
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(i~., list(i = as.name(x))), data = test) 
})
```

And then run stepwise, but backward.

```
lapply(models, function(x){step(x,direction="backward")})
```